# ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class view.Addition

Tags: oracle-adf

I am new to ADF, I am doing adding of two numbers. Created two files:

1. AdditionNumbers.jspx
2. Addition

When I run the Application, am getting below error:

> Root cause of ServletException.

```
oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'view.Addition'
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.Utils.createAndLogFacesException(Utils.java:184)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:192)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:873)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getUncachedReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:409)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.isReadOnly(LabeledInputRenderer.java:294)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.getClientComponentType(LabeledInputRenderer.java:86)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1300)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:220)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1341)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:979)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:408)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'view.Addition'
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:276)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:186)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:873)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getUncachedReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:409)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.isReadOnly(LabeledInputRenderer.java:294)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.getClientComponentType(LabeledInputRenderer.java:86)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1300)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:220)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1341)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:979)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:408)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: view/Addition : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:186)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:873)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.isReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getUncachedReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.EditableValueRenderer.getReadOnly(EditableValueRenderer.java:409)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.isReadOnly(LabeledInputRenderer.java:294)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.LabeledInputRenderer.getClientComponentType(LabeledInputRenderer.java:86)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1300)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:220)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1341)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:979)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:408)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
 SUBSYSTEM = HTTP USERID = <WLS Kernel> SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-101017 MACHINE = BNGW8-MJOGAR TXID =  CONTEXTID = 7a896e0ea900a80f:-4f901b37:15aec18d3a5:-8000-0000000000000024 TIMESTAMP = 1490019933124  
WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset 
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000 
> 
<20 Mar, 2017 7:55:35 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:59,246 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<20 Mar, 2017 7:55:35 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:59,247 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<20 Mar, 2017 7:55:35 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:59,249 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<20 Mar, 2017 7:55:35 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:59,248 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<20 Mar, 2017 7:55:35 PM IST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:59,245 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl> <createADR`enter code here`Incident> incident 2 created with problem key "DFW-99998 [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError][oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance][AddingTwoNumbers]"
```

Comment: Hi Forum, can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

i think you may have done the binding of method made in impl class in page defination of jsf page.

can you say more specifically what you have used exactly including taskflows and backing bean. post your code here.